# Connection Timeout when doing docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

On doing docker-compose up, I get the following error. What could be the reason for this?

```
Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/mysql/manifests/8.0.23": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.107.1:53: read udp 192.168.107.2:37484->192.168.107.1:53: i/o timeout
```

This is how docker file looks like

```
version: '3'
services:
  local_ms_db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    container_name: local_ms_db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=m_service
      - MYSQL_USER=ms
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test_password
    networks:
      - local_ms_network
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT:-3307}:3306"
  local_ms_db_init:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    depends_on:
      - local_ms_db
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    container_name: local_ms_db_init
    networks:
      - local_ms_network
    volumes:
      - "../src/main/resources/db/schema.sql:/schema.sql"
      - "./seed.sql:/seed.sql"
    command: bash -c "
        until mysql -u ms --password=test_password -h local_ms_db m_service < /schema.sql; do echo MySQL is unavailable to initialize, retry in 5 seconds; sleep 5; done;
        until mysql -u ms --password=test_password -h local_ms_db m_service < /seed.sql; do echo MySQL is unavailable to be seeded, retry in 5 seconds; sleep 5; done;
      "
networks:
  local_ms_network:
```

I have tried restarting docker, didn't workout.
PS: I am behind a wirewall. But that should not be the reason behind this error!

Comment: Does Docker work properly on your machine? If not sure, try to run `docker run hello-world`. This will pull an image from docker hub and run it. It should output some text like "Hello from Docker!" and so on.

Comment: I get the same error while doing docker pull hello-world. I have uninstalled and reinstalled colima but still I am getting same response. My company doesn't allow me to use docker desktop hence I am using colima. 
I installed colima using brew install colima

Comment: I guess your company blocks access to some domains used by Docker and that's why get timeouts when trying to pull images. Probably you should talk with your company's admins or your boss and try to make them remove these restrictions.